# text input to variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to get the data written in two text inputs saved into variables.

This is my **rtmNav.html**:

```
<div class="rtm-nav">
<label>From:
        <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="ctrl.dataa.from">
    </label>
    <label>To:
        <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="ctrl.dataa.to">
    </label>
</div>
```

This is the controller that already exists. I cannot change it's structure and imo it looks different compared to a classic one. I must add the variables here:

**demand.js**

```
class DemandCtrl {
    constructor(ChartDataService) {
        this.ChartDataService = ChartDataService;
    }

    $onInit() {
        getData.call(null, this);       
    }
    /////////////// THIS IS WHERE I GUESS I SHOULD ADD THE VARIABLES
    this.dataa = {
        from: '',
        to: ''
    };
    ////////////
}

... other methods ...

export const Demand = {
    bindings: {
        data: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: demandPageHtml,
    controller: DemandCtrl
};
```

Probably it is not the correct way to add it here like that because I get this message from my code editor:

> [js] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property
>   was expected.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Put your variable declaration into the `constructor`

```
class DemandCtrl {

    constructor(ChartDataService) {
        this.ChartDataService = ChartDataService;
        this.dataa = {
            from: '',
            to: ''
        };
    }

    $onInit() {
        getData.call(null, this);       
    }

}
```

Comment: might wanna declare the variable.